# Interpreting function calls in with sphinx

Tags: fortran, python-sphinx

We have a bunch of lines (in fortran 95/2003) like

```
call param_register(dictionary_object, "key", "default_value", variable, help_string="some help regarding key")
```

I would like to generate documentation with sphinx where it lists the keys, the contents of the associated `help_string` and perhaps the default values. How could I make sphinx to interpret these lines?

Comment: Sphinx has no built-in support for Fortran. But https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinx-fortran might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I have already been using this package and as far as I can tell it only interprets appropriately placed comments - but here I really want it to use stuff from the codebase.